# Build Django Query Dynamically based on kendo UI filter

Tags: python-3.x, django, kendo-grid

I'm trying to query a database based on user filter. i received following input from kendo UI grid.

```
{
   "filter":{
      "filters":[
         {
            "logic":"or",
            "filters":[
               {
                  "field":"aging",
                  "operator":"eq",
                  "value":24
               },
               {
                  "field":"aging",
                  "operator":"eq",
                  "value":13
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "logic":"or",
            "filters":[
               {
                  "field":"follow_up_name",
                  "operator":"eq",
                  "value":"Call Insurance Provider"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "logic":"or",
            "filters":[
               {
                  "field":"patient_name",
                  "operator":"eq",
                  "value":"kartik"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "logic":"and",
            "filters":[
               {
                  "field":"created_date",
                  "operator":"eq",
                  "value":"2022-01-09T18:30:00.000Z"
               },
               {
                  "field":"created_date",
                  "operator":"gte",
                  "value":"2022-01-04T18:30:00.000Z"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "logic":"or",
            "filters":[
               {
                  "field":"follow_up_status",
                  "operator":"eq",
                  "value":"Open"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "logic":"or",
            "filters":[
               {
                  "field":"role_name",
                  "operator":"eq",
                  "value":"Pharmacist"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "logic":"or",
            "filters":[
               {
                  "field":"last_response",
                  "operator":"eq",
                  "value":"To-Patient"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "logic":"and"
   },
   "skip":0,
   "take":10
}
```

Based on above data i need both 'and' & 'or' condition to build query dynamically. and pass it to database. also filter can contain multiple list. also want to make these class common which can take only UI arguments build query and return. please provide a solution for these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q objects are your friend here.

```
from django.db.models import QuerySet, Q
from functools import reduce

def filter_rec(data: dict) -> Q:
    logic = data.get('logic', None)
    # Leaf node
    if logic is None:
        field = data['field']
        operator = data['operator']
        value = data['value']
        return Q(**{f'{field}__{operator}': value})
    # Node with children
    children = list()
    for item in data['filters']:
        child = filter_rec(child)
        children.append(child)
    if logic == 'and':
        query = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, children)
    elif logic == 'or':
        query = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, children)
    return query

def kendo_filter(data: dict, qs: QuerySet) -> QuerySet:
    query = filter_rec(data['filter'])
    skip = data['skip']
    take = data['take']
    filtered_qs = qs.filter(query)
    paginated_qs = filtered_qs[skip:skip+take]
    return paginated_qs
```

The general gist is this. It is up to you to validate the data and do error handling.

`filter_rec(data['filter'])` returns the following for your example data:

```
 <Q: (
    AND: 
        (OR: ('aging__eq', 24), ('aging__eq', 13)), 
        ('follow_up_name__eq', 'Call Insurance Provider'), 
        ('patient_name__eq', 'kartik'), 
        ('created_date__eq', '2022-01-09T18:30:00.000Z'), 
        ('created_date__gte', '2022-01-04T18:30:00.000Z'), 
        ('follow_up_status__eq', 'Open'), 
        ('role_name__eq', 'Pharmacist'), 
        ('last_response__eq', 'To-Patient')
)>
```

Since single ORs would be lifted as is and nested ANDs would show up as a single level, it seems to have worked.